# Como ubicar etiqueta con nombre al lado de foto

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-3

Estoy en el desarrollo de unos boxes y me encuentro con el problema en que no se como ubicar el nombre al lado de la fotografía, actualmente se ubica la etiqueta debajo de la fotografia, lo que se requiere es que se ubique a un lado como la imagen de ejemplo.

La versión que utilizo en mi es **Bootstrap 3.3.7**

```css
.box.box-primary {
    border-top-color: #3c8dbc;
}

.box {
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: #ffffff;
    border-top: 3px solid #d2d6de;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgb(0 0 0 / 10%);
}

.box-header:before, .box-body:before, .box-footer:before, .box-header:after, .box-body:after, .box-footer:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}

.list-unstyled, .chart-legend, .contacts-list, .users-list, .mailbox-attachments {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.users-list>li {
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}

.users-list>li img {
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 50px;
    height: 100%;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 20px;
}

.users-list-name {
    font-weight: 600;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.users-list-name, .users-list-date {
    display: block;
}

a {
    color: #3c8dbc;
}

.users-list-date {
    color: #999;
    font-size: 12px;
}

.users-list-name, .users-list-date {
    display: block;
}

@media (min-width: 992px)
.col-md-2 {
    width: 16.66666667%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="col-md-4">
<div class="box box-primary">
                <div class="box-body no-padding">
                    <ul class="users-list clearfix">
                    <li>
                      <img src="https://adminlte.io/themes/AdminLTE/dist/img/user1-128x128.jpg" alt="User Image">
                      <h2>Etiqueta</h2>
                      <a class="users-list-name" href="#">Detalles</a>
                      <span class="users-list-date">Today</span>
                    </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="box-body no-padding">
                    <ul class="users-list clearfix">
                    <li>
                      <img src="https://adminlte.io/themes/AdminLTE/dist/img/user3-128x128.jpg" alt="User Image">
                      <a class="users-list-name" href="#">Detalles</a>
                      <span class="users-list-date">Today</span>
                    </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <!-- /.box-body -->
            </div>

</div>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: @BetaM Exactamente el nombre Etiqueta es el que quiero ubicar al lado de la imagen, asi como en el ejemplo al final del snippet

Comment: Difícil que quepan la foto y la etiqueta en un li al 25%.

Comment: @BetaM Es correcto, Detalles y Today permanecer debajo de la imagen

Comment: @Sal Es valido que se cambie el tamaño de fuente o se reduzca un poco el tamaño de la imagen, por eso no hay problema

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Le agregué la clase **etiqueta** al **h2** con contenido etiqueta. Y con esa clase puse **display inline-block**. Y para que la etiqueta se suba a lado de la imagen es necesario **aumentar el ancho del li**.

```css
.box.box-primary {
    border-top-color: #3c8dbc;
}

.box {
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: #ffffff;
    border-top: 3px solid #d2d6de;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgb(0 0 0 / 10%);
}

.box-header:before, .box-body:before, .box-footer:before, .box-header:after, .box-body:after, .box-footer:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}

.list-unstyled, .chart-legend, .contacts-list, .users-list, .mailbox-attachments {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.users-list>li {
    width: 40%;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}

.users-list>li img {
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 40px;
    height: 100%;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 20px;
}

.users-list-name {
    font-weight: 600;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.users-list-name, .users-list-date {
    display: block;
}

a {
    color: #3c8dbc;
}

.users-list-date {
    color: #999;
    font-size: 12px;
}

.users-list-name, .users-list-date {
    display: block;
}

.etiqueta {
    display: inline-block;
}

/* @media (min-width: 992px)
.col-md-2 {
    width: 16.66666667%;
} */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./index.css">
</head>

<body>


    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="box box-primary">
            <div class="box-body no-padding">
                <ul class="users-list clearfix">
                    <li>
                        <img src="https://adminlte.io/themes/AdminLTE/dist/img/user1-128x128.jpg" alt="User Image">
                        <h2 class="etiqueta">Etiqueta</h2>
                        <a class="users-list-name" href="#">Detalles</a>
                        <span class="users-list-date">Today</span>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="box-body no-padding">
                <ul class="users-list clearfix">
                    <li>
                        <img src="https://adminlte.io/themes/AdminLTE/dist/img/user3-128x128.jpg" alt="User Image">
                        <h2 class="etiqueta">Etiqueta</h2>
                        <a class="users-list-name" href="#">Detalles</a>
                        <span class="users-list-date">Today</span>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.box-body -->
        </div>

        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


        <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Excelente respuesta clara y concisa